# NSWindowFlipper in cocoa mac os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i want to animate my two window using NSWindowFlipper [i get the code from here](https://github.com/mizage/Flip-Animation) now i want to call that animation class how can i call that flipper class 
this is my window

```
   IBOutlet    NSWindow  *from ;
    IBOutlet   NSWindow * to;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import "NSWindow+Additions" and "NSWindowFlipper" classes to Your project. If You want to call this class You need button with "NSWindowFlipper" launch code.

```
-(IBAction)call:(id)sender {

    [from flipToWindow:to withDuration:2.5 shadowed:NO];
}
```

Don't forget to import in buttons class .h "NSWindowFlipper" like so:

```
#import "NSWindowFlipper.h"
```

For example this class can be like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSWindowFlipper.h"


@interface CallClass : NSObject {

    IBOutlet NSWindow* from;
    IBOutlet NSWindow* to;
}

-(IBAction)call:(id)sender;

@end
```

Don't forget IBOutlet Your windows and button!! Uncheck "Visible At Launch" to Your "to" window.

And Your class .m can be like so:

```
#import "CallClass.h"

@implementation CallClass

-(IBAction)call:(id)sender {

    [from flipToWindow:to withDuration:2.5 shadowed:NO];
}

@end
```

So I think Your problem was because You forget to import header file "NSWindowFlipper.h" to Your's class header file.

Now everything should work. Good luck!